# Is it possible to prevent illegal url access frm anyone but file owner, if using paperclip url hash parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

Paperclip hash can hide the actual file path, but the url itself stays public wch anyone other than the actual owner of file, can access.

in many online guides the method listed was simply to serve the file through "sendfile" ruby class, which take an "id" and then activate the download.

but if the paperclip hash parameter is used, it simply would not work, as "sendfile" cant understand the hash.

this is what i did.

paperclip asset.rb model file i have

```
:url => "/system/:hash.:extension"
```

now in my route file, i have

```
 match "/system/:hash.:extension" => "assets#get", :as => "download"
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to asset.doc_name, download_url(asset) %>
```

assets controller

```
def get  
asset = current_user.assets.find_by_id(params[:id])  
if asset  
     send_file asset.uploaded_doc.path, :type => asset.uploaded_doc_content_type  
end  
end
```

this generates no route match error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"assets", :action=>"get", :hash=>#<Asset id: 25, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-27 15:06:55", updated_at: "2014-02-27 15:06:55", uploaded_doc_file_name: "warm.jpg", uploaded_doc_content_type: "image/jpeg", uploaded_doc_file_size: 39627, uploaded_doc_updated_at: "2014-02-27 15:06:55">}
```

**but if i dont use hash, instead use something like
`:url=>"/assets/get/:id"` in asset.rb and make the changes in routes, it will work.**

from the error it seems it is expecting some hash. how to make it understand its paperclip's parameter and get "sendfile" to work with it.

(i was learning to code a file storage app from [here](http://codyaray.com/downloads/2012/03/How-to-Build-a-Dropbox-like-Sharing-App-using-Ruby-on-Rails.html))

Comment: this did not help - https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1222